# Until sometime ago + present perfect or past perfect?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

I always see this structure(1) in movies, tv series etc. but I think this structure is grammatically incorrect. I suppose I would use this structure in a daily conversation but not in a essay or a academic paper. I would use the past perfect version(2) instead. Am I right ?

> 1-No one ***has ever seen*** anything like it ***until two days
>   ago.***
>
> 2-No one ***had ever seen*** anything like it ***until two days
>   ago.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is correct. You are talking about some event prior to a time in the past, so you need a past tense.

The first is quite common in speech, because of how our mind works:

> Nobody has ever seen a black hole {thinks, remembers extra detail} until the EHT made an image of M87.

It is an error. But a very common one.

Comment: Thank you but still some native speakers insist on saying the first one is correct if I am speaking in present moment.

Comment: Whether it is correct, or a common error isn't worth an argument. The meaning is clear enough.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Which version would you use if you were to write a essay or something formal?

Comment: I'd use the second. But I wouldn't condemn someone who used the first.